# C# Hex string from library shown 'decoded' in intellisense & metadata

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an annoying but not functional problem.  I have a library that's compiled and distributed via an internal nuget and in there is a file containing hex values for font awesome. eg:
`public const string AddressBook = "\uf2b9";`

When this is referenced within the library the intellisense shows as the \u string above.

However, when the library is used in another project and also when viewing the metadata for the file the value is shown as:
`public const string AddressBook = "";`

[image: intellisense]

Is there a way of specifying, either in the consumer or the source (maybe through an attribute), that the string should be displayed in its 'raw' \u form?

All the best,

Comment: Not sure if there are something wrong with your internal nuget or the parse of this value from Visual Studio. If you try to create a new simple class library project and add the “const string…” to it, then refer it from another newly created empty project, will this issue persists?

Comment: Yes it does.  If I add via Assembly reference (dll) then it persists.  If I add the project to the solution, then add as a Project Reference then the issue is fixed

Comment: The `\u...` construct is not a "hex code" but a char that is specified by its unicode value. The debugger tries to display that character (`'\u20ac'` would be the same as `'€'`), however as a "private use" character, there is no standard glyph for it

Comment: Okay, makes sense, do you know if there's any way to stop the debugger displaying the character and show the unicode string instead?